# Order of arguments matter when calling C function using ctypes

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

Source of my C dll:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int nums[5];
    int tp;
} Sample;

float read_float(Sample s, float* arg){
    return arg[1];
}
```

Source of Python code calling it:

```
from ctypes import *

class PySample(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("nums", c_int * 5),
                ("tp", c_int)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    libp = CDLL(r"PathToMyDLL")
    rf = libp.read_float
    rf.restype = c_float
    s = PySample()
    for i in range(5):
        s.nums[i] = (11,22,33,44,55)[i]
    s.tp = 101
    print(rf(s, (c_float*3)(0.4, 0.5, 0.6)))
```

After compiling with gcc -shared and running the Python code I get some random small number.
However if I change signature of C function to:

```
float read_float(float* arg, Sample s)
```

and corresponding Python print call to:

```
print(rf((c_float*3)(0.4, 0.5, 0.6), s))
```

(that is changing order of arguments in both definition and function call) then I get correct 0.5

That isn't desired behavior. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here and why it is happening?

(Python 3.4.1 for 64bit Windows and C code is compiled with gcc 4.8.1 (MinGw-W64))

Comment: Your original order's wrong, do you mean `read_float(float* arg, Sample s)`?

Comment: Yes, I've got confused copy-pasting the code (now corrected); the point is that the code work if the array of floats is first (in both definition and calling code) and it doesn't work if the struct is first.

Comment: Maybe `Sample`'s alignment isn't right, tried playing with `_pack_`?

Comment: I tried specifying _pack_ = 1 but it doesn't help. I don't understand those issues too well but it seems to me that alignment shouldn't matter as I am not using anything from passed struct (in the minimalistic example I gave). Anyway, any explanation/fix would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess to specify function signature like `rf.argtypes = [PySample, c_float_p]` before making a call.

Comment: I don't know how/if ctypes converts it but it does work and I can read the floats in C function (you can try and compile it, those are working examples). Passing the pointer (created by ctypes.POINTER) or using ctypes.byref doesn't change anything. It also works if all other arguments are non structs (I have a function with 2 arrays and some ints for example), the only thing which ruins it is putting a struct as first argument so my guess is that I do something wrong with passing the struct but I have no idea what it could be.

Answer (score 2):

If you add an `argtypes` declaration, your examples work correctly when compiled 32-bit and used with 32-bit Python:

```
rf.argtypes = [PySample, POINTER(c_float)]
```

But in 64-bit Python, if fails. I found that changing the `argtypes` to use a pointer to the structure made it work, even though C is passing the structure by value.

```
rf.argtypes = [POINTER(PySample), POINTER(c_float)]
```

BUT, If I changed your functions to modify the structure, it modified it in Python as well.  Calling the function from C and actually passing by value did not modify the structure in the caller as expected, so this seems like a bug in 64-bit `ctypes`.

Comment: I checked the 64-bit version (VC++) in a debugger. With `argtypes = [PySample, POINTER(c_float)]`, ctypes passes a pointer to the struct in register `rcx`. That's mostly correct since the aggregate is larger than 8 bytes; however, it isn't creating a temporary copy to honor the by-value parameter. Then it puts who knows what junk in `rdx` and `r8` and decides to pass the 2nd arg in `r9`. The 2nd arg belongs in `rdx`. Manually setting `argtypes` to use `POINTER(PySample)` does work around this bug.

Comment: Probably the struct's 24 bytes are reserved on the stack, even though it's passing a pointer. This moves the 2nd arg out to the shadow space of register `r9`. Then the shadow space is copied to registers `rcx`, `rdx`, `r8`, and `r9` before calling the function.

Comment: So it seems another way to go around this is just put the struct arguments at the end of a function signature but it won't work with more than one of them. Does it qualify for a bug report ?